# How can I use TimeOnly and DateOnly in .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I't doesn't matter what code I post because .NET 6 has `TimeOnly` and `DateOnly`. Is there a way I can use it in .NET Framework 4.8? Can I add a reference somewhere or is it not possible to be able to use DateOnly and TimeOnly.

Here is the code that I wrote in .NET 6 and now want to use in .NET Framework 4.8

```
public TimeOnly Time = new TimeOnly();
public DateOnly Date = new DateOnly();
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rc7V.png)

Answer (score 11):

Those types exist out of the box only in .Net 6+, so they are not available in older versions.

However, you can add them manually. For example, using this NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.System.DateTimeOnly

It will add those types to your .Net Framework projects, and they should behave relatively the same as .Net 6 ones (see more info in NuGet's description).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use `TimeOnly` and `DateOnly` types on .NET Framework. Those types were introduced in .NET 6 and will not be backported on .NET Framework.

Some time ago, I tried to compile them for .NET Standard (which would make them available on .NET Framework) but as expected, it was a huge amount of work because their implementation depends on *many* types which are also only available on .NET 6. While this would probably be technically possible, it's definitely not worth the effort.

I can think of two solutions for you.

1. Migrate your .NET Framework 4.8 app to .NET 6
2. Take a dependency on NodaTime and use the equivalent [LocalTime](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.LocalTime.html) and [LocalDate](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDate.html) types instead